# How to connect existing mysql and phpmyadmin to new zend server ce

Tags: zend-framework

Hi I am moving to Zend server from Xampp such that I can easily run Zend Studio. I have an existing implementation og PHPmyAdmin and MySQL. These need to now be pointed towards the Zend server, which has it's own copy of Apache.

I am struggling to figure out how to do this - Many Thanks for your advice.

Comment: I don't have experience with Zend Server.. But my guess i that you can download phpmyadmin (web or repository) and configure apache via a alias or by putting it on the root of your localhost web location (only if it's NOT a development server). Basicly nothing changed only the name. Also make sure your Zend Server has mysql installed on it

Comment: I usually just backup my databases and the kill the old installation and then let Zend Server CE install all of it (Then I restore the backups). Especially because ZSCE will use the ver 5.1.5 of Mysql, at least that was the last version I got. The good thing about ZSCE is when it's done it's done, all you have to do is your vhosts.